# Unable to start locally-built ntpd from system service script

Tags: init-script, ntpd

I built ntpd from source, which process put it in /usr/local/sbin. Of course, the ntp service points to /usr/sbin. So, I thought I could just change the path in the init.d configuration file like this:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:        ntp
# Required-Start:  $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:   $network $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:   2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:
# Short-Description: Start NTP daemon
### END INIT INFO

PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

. /lib/lsb/init-functions

DAEMON=/usr/local/sbin/ntpd
PIDFILE=/var/run/ntpd.pid
...[etc]
```

I changed the line starting with "DAEMON" to point to the location of the new binary. However, when I try to restart the service I get the error:

```
[ ok ] Stopping NTP server: ntpd.
[....] Starting NTP server: ntpd/usr/local/sbin/ntpd: The 'user' option has been disabled. -- built without --enable-clockctl or --enable-linuxcaps or --enable-solarisprivs
ntpd - NTP daemon program - Ver. 4.2.7p475
Usage:  ntpd [ -<flag> [<val>] | --<name>[{=| }<val>] ]... \
                [ <server1> ... <serverN> ]
Try 'ntpd --help' for more information.
 failed!
```

How can I have the service run from /usr/local/sbin instead of /usr/sbin?

**Solution (based on accepted answer):**

Apparently when building on Linux you need to use the switch `--enable-linuxcaps` when building on Linux. Here are the steps necessary on Debian Wheezy:

```
cd ~/install/ntp-dev-4.2.7p475     # or wherever you have the source unpacked
make clean                         # clean out the previous build
sudo apt-get install libcap-dev    # this library is required by linuxcaps
./configure --enable-linuxcaps     # this is the critical switch
make
sudo make install
sudo /etc/init.d/ntp restart       # restart ntp
ntpq -c "rv 0 version"             # make sure you are running the right version
```

The only line you have change in /etc/init.d/ntp is the DAEMON line, as said above.

Comment: What distro are you running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've built `ntpd` without the `--enable-linuxcaps` option. Without this, `ntpd` won't recognise the *user* option `-u`.

Your options are:

- Recompile with the correct option
- Remove the `-u $UGID` from the `NTPD_OPTS` line in `/etc/init.d/ntp`

Comment: That worked. I updated the question.

Comment: Congrats on getting to 5k. Keep up the good work!